# Scala initializing class level Array variable within a method

Tags: arrays, scala

```
class Foo() {
 val array  // how do I leave initialization till later?
 def initializeArray(size : Int) = array = Array.ofDim[Int](size)
}
```

The above code won't compile, so how do I initialize my array at a later time?

## Edit

Suppose I need to read a file that has a matrix of integer, and I want to represent the matrix as a two dimensional array.  Of course, I am parsing the file inside the `Foo` class and the dimension of the matrix won't be known until the parsing is done.

Comment: Why do you need to leave initialization till later? It might be there's a better solution than "leave initialization till later".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way would be to just initialize it to `null`.  To do this you would need to specify a type, `Array[Int]` and to make it a `var` (instead of `val`) so that you could change it later:

```
class Foo() {
  var array: Array[Int] = null  // how do I leave initialization till later?
  def initializeArray(size : Int) = array = Array.ofDim[Int](size)
}
```

However, this is not very good practice in Scala.  It might be better to use an `Option`:

```
class Foo() {
  var array: Option[Array[Int]] = None  // how do I leave initialization till later?
  def initializeArray(size : Int) = array = Some(Array.ofDim[Int](size))
}
```

This tells a user, explicitly, that it is possible that `array` may not be set to anything, and avoids `NullPointerException`s.  You can read more about `Option` on StackOverflow or elsewhere.

Finally, the best designs in Scala rely on *immutable* classes.  In such a case, you would defer creation of the `Foo` until you actually know what you want to put in it.  However, without knowing anything else about your design, it's hard to say how best to set this up.

EDIT: Based on your description, I would separate your design into two parts: a method for parsing the file, and an immutable `Foo` for storing the final result.

```
class Foo(array: Array[Int]) {

}

object Foo {
  def fromFile() = {
     val array: Array[Int] = /* parse file into the right structure */
     new Foo(array)
  }
}
```

Then you could just say:

```
val foo = Foo.fromFile(filename)
```

and the `foo` would be an complete, immutable `Foo`.

Comment: I figured as much, what would be an alternative to what I am trying to do? See my edit

Comment: @qin, Edited based on your requirement

Answer (score 4):

You could use a lazy val e.g.

```
scala> class Foo {
     | lazy val array = initialize
     | def initialize = {
     | println("initializing...")
     | new Array[Int](5)
     | }
     | }
defined class Foo

scala> val f = new Foo
f: Foo = Foo@135810c

scala> f.array
initializing...
res46: Array[Int] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Now you have deferred when the array is initialized.